# Symfony Console Commands in scheduler in TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I wrote a symfony controller command which works as expected in cli. But I would prefer to trigger the script via scheduler. Is there a possibility to get the symfony command in the tasks of scheduler? (TYPO3 8)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own task for scheduler as described in documentation of EXT:scheduler https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-scheduler/master/en-us/DevelopersGuide/CreatingTasks/Index.html

```
class MyTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask {
        public function execute() {
                $businessLogic = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\Vendor\Extension\BusinessLogic::class);
                $businessLogic->run(arg1, arg2, …);
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the result is an error message: "The command defined in "Vendor\Myext\Command\ImporterCommand" cannot have an empty name.